# Parse xml attributes into strings

Tags: python, xml, parsing

If I have an xml attribute that is declared like:

```
for child in  root:
  print(child.attrib)
```

and it prints out all of my child nodes:

```
{'action': 'Stay', 'response': ''}
{'action': 'Enemy Charging User', 'response': ''}
{'action': 'Move', 'response': ''}
```

is there a way I can just convert the actions to a string list where I can use the elements from it? for example 'Stay', 'Enemy Charging User', and 'Move' would convert to strings and be stored into a string list called l1[] where I can say call l1[0] and print out 'Stay'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l1 = [ child.attrib['action'] for child in root ]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking. But just to expand on it, say if I were to use different xml files with different attribute names, is there a way I can do this without changing the ['action'] attribute to match the xml file every time?

Comment: You'd have to figure out what the appropriate replacement was. Certainly you could replace `'action'` with a variable in the expression above.